# Consulta: Contar y luego sacar el valor máximo en SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

Quiero establecer cuál es la agencia que mas facturas a vendido en el año 2022
La primera tabla es DetalleVenta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la segunda FacturaVenta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A partir de esto lo que he realizado es

```
SELECT COUNT(e.IDFacturaV) AS NUM_facturas, d.IDAgencia, a.Nombre FROM DetalleVenta e
JOIN FacturaVenta d
ON e.IDFacturaV=d.IDFacturaV 
JOIN Agencia a
ON d.IDAgencia = a.IDAgencia
WHERE YEAR(e.Fech)= '2022'
GROUP BY d.IDAgencia, a.Nombre
```

Dándome la siguiente tabla, sin embargo, deseo obtener el máximo, el máximo de la cuenta de IDFacturaV, es decir en este caso solo la agencia que tiene dos facturas contadas (NUM_facturas = 2).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrias poner `limit 1`, y con esto ya estarías haciendo que te enseñe solo un registro, sino también podrias poner `select top 1 COUNT(e.IDFacturaV)...`

Answer (score 1):

El escenario:

```
Create table DetalleVenta(idDetalleVenta varchar(10), idFacturaV varchar(10), Fech date)
Create table FacturaVenta (idFacturaV varchar(10),  idCliente varchar(10), idAgencia varchar(10))
Create table Agencia (idAgencia varchar(10), Nombre varchar(15));
```

Alguna tabla no tiene todas las columnas porque no aporta valor.

```
INSERT INTO DetalleVenta (idDetalleVenta,idFacturaV, Fech)
VALUES
('DETV001','FACTV001','20220730'),
('DETV002','FACTV002','20220730'),
('DETV003','FACTV003','20220731'),
('DETV004','FACTV004','20220731'),
('DETV005','FACTV005','20220801');
INSERT INTO FacturaVenta (idFacturaV,idCliente, idAgencia)
values
('FACTV001','CLI001','AG001'),
('FACTV002','CLI002','AG002'),
('FACTV003','CLI003','AG001'),
('FACTV004','CLI004','AG003'),
('FACTV005','CLI005','AG004');
INSERT INTO Agencia (idAgencia, Nombre)
values
('AG001','ECUAMOTORS'),
('AG002','ECUAMOTORS2'),
('AG003','ECUAMOTORS3'),
('AG004','ECUAMOTORS4'),
('AG005','ECUAMOTORS5');
```

Existen muchas maneras de lograr lo que solicitas, pero la más didáctica es usar una cte para tener los datos, y de la salida recoger solo lo que queremos.

En el caso de la pregunta, el registro mayor. Y mayor significa el primero por Num_Facturas.

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT Count(e.IDFacturaV) AS NUM_facturas
     , d.IDAgencia
     , a.Nombre
       FROM DetalleVenta AS e
            JOIN FacturaVenta AS d ON e.IDFacturaV = d.IDFacturaV
            JOIN Agencia AS a ON d.IDAgencia = a.IDAgencia
       WHERE Year(e.Fech) = 2022
       GROUP BY d.IDAgencia
              , a.Nombre
)
SELECT top(1) *
FROM CTE 
order by NUM_facturas desc;
```

[image: Res]

Ahora tienes que plantearte que registro quieres, caso de que hubiera dos agencias con 2 facturas.

- (Las 2: Investiga Top With Ties).
- (1 sola: Investiga order by debería ser determinista).